# HTTP Error 404: Not Found when using wget to download a link

Tags: python, wget

This is the code being used:

```
import wget

firefox_29 = "https://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/firefox/releases/29.0.1/win32/en-
US/Firefox%20Setup%2029.0.1.exe"

firefox_dir = 'C:\\firefox\\firefox29'

wget.download(firefox_29, out=firefox_dir)
```

This is the error I get, I've used wget before in the same way and it's worked fine so I'm confused as to why this error occurs. Also the link is a working link.

[image]

Comment: Check for your URL. If it's a 404, it may come from it.

Comment: the url works, if i click on it, it will download.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to figure it out without using wget. Apparently wget is just a wrapper for urllib. So I used urlretrieve instead. Heres the code:

```
import urllib.request

firefox_29 = "https://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/firefox/releases/29.0.1/win32/en-
US/Firefox%20Setup%2029.0.1.exe"

urllib.request.urlretrieve(firefox_29, 'firefox29.exe')
```

However this just renames the .exe to "firefox29.exe", so if you need it downloaded to a specific location you just have to move it yourself.

Answer (score 6):

I also faced the same problem before some minutes, so found this question.
I first installed `wget` with

```
pip install wget
```

then I faced this problem...
After digging a little, I uninstalled it, with...

```
pip uninstall wget
```

And then used...

```
pip install python3-wget
```

The problem was solved.

Comment: Would appreciate some more context, what did you find in your digging? `python3-wget` doesn't even have a [formal release](https://pypi.org/project/python3-wget/#history), so I'd guess it's not the best idea for production code.